# Grails 3: HTTP Client

Tags: grails

I'm migrating my Grails 2.3.6 projects to Grails 3. Ever since back, I was using httpbuilder by integrating

```
compile ":rest:0.8"
```

Compiler says "Could not find :rest:0.8.", I tried to add

```
maven { url "http://grails.org/plugins" }
```

but with no success. What httpclient am I supposed to use? The doc seems to lack this information.

Comment: Are you sure that syntax works in a gradle build file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed it using this line in buld.gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', name: 'http-builder', version: '0.7.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

did you mean [this?](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.grails/grails-plugin-rest/2.3.0.M2)

maybe this will help you

[how to call withHttp() with http builder helper plugin grails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868187/how-to-call-withhttp-with-http-builder-helper-plugin-grails-3)